# Converting .PB files to .ONNX using C#

Tags: c#, tensorflow, onnx, ml.net, onnxruntime

I'm looking to convert to TensorFlow model (.pb) to .ONNX so I can use in C#.

From what I read, this is possible using the ONNX runtime nuget. However, Visual Studio states type or namespace `OnnxModel` cannot be found, so I've read conflicting information. I know there is methods in Python, but I'm interested in C# only .pb>.onnx conversions.

```
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime;

    namespace FineTuningML
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                
                // Load the EfficientNetB0 model.
                var model = new OnnxModel(File.ReadAllBytes("efficientnet_b0.pb"));
    
                // Convert the TensorFlow model to ONNX.
                var onnxModel = model.ConvertToOnnxModel();
    
                // Save the ONNX model to a file.
                File.WriteAllBytes("efficientnet_b0.onnx", onnxModel);
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!